# ConnectionFactory creating too many connections from .net core registered service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, dbconnectionfactory

I have inserted a connection factory based LinqToDB service in the .Net Core.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped<IDatabase, Database>( provider =>
                {
                    IConfigurationSection sqlConfig = Configuration.GetSection("Database");
                    IDataProvider dataProvider = new SqlServerDataProvider("SqlServer", SqlServerVersion.v2008);

                    return new Database(dataProvider,
                        new WorkspaceConnectionFactory(
                        sqlConfig["clientId"],
                        sqlConfig["clientSecret"],
                        sqlConfig["authority"],
                        sqlConfig["target"],
                        sqlConfig["connectionString"]).createConnection());
                });
```

with this implementation of factory

```
namespace Workspace.Common.LinqToDB
{
    public class WorkspaceConnectionFactory
    {
        private ClientCredential ClientCredential;
        private string Authority;
        private string Target;
        private string ConnectionString;

        public WorkspaceConnectionFactory(string clientId, string clientSecret, string authority, string target, string connectionString)
        {
            ClientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
            Authority = authority;
            Target = target;
            ConnectionString = connectionString;
        }

        public IDbConnection createConnection()
        {
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(Target, ClientCredential).Result;
            SqlConnection WorkspaceDataConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            WorkspaceDataConnection.AccessToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

            return WorkspaceDataConnection;
        }
    }
}
```

After successful connection and a few queries, I get the following exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Resource ID : 1. The request limit for the database is 90 and has been reached. See 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=267637' for assistance.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior commandBehavior) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Data\DataConnection.cs:line 1227
>      at LinqToDB.Linq.QueryRunner.ExecuteQuery[T](Query query, IDataContext dataContext, Mapper`1 mapper, Expression expression, Object[] ps, Int32 queryNumber)+MoveNext() in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\QueryRunner.cs:line 320
>      at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.TableBuilder.AssociatedTableContext.SubQueryHelper`1.ExecuteSubQuery(IQueryRunner queryRunner, Object parentObject, Func`3 queryReader)+MoveNext() in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\Builder\TableBuilder.AssociatedTableContext.cs:line 460
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , IQueryRunner , IDataReader )
>      at LinqToDB.Linq.QueryRunner.Mapper`1.Map(IQueryRunner queryRunner, IDataReader dataReader) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\QueryRunner.cs:line 56
>      at LinqToDB.Linq.QueryRunner.ExecuteQuery[T](Query query, IDataContext dataContext, Mapper`1 mapper, Expression expression, Object[] ps, Int32 queryNumber)+MoveNext() in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\QueryRunner.cs:line 324
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.UnionIterator`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Set`1.UnionWith(IEnumerable`1 other)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.DistinctIterator`1.FillSet()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.DistinctIterator`1.ToArray()
>
> .........................
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>      at Workspace.API.Middlewares.AddUserHeadersMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IWorkspaceRepository workspaceRepository) in C:\TFS\AT_NCSWorkspace\WorkSpaceAPI\src\API\Middlewares\AddUserHeadersMiddleware.cs:line 47
>      at Workspace.API.Middlewares.ErrorLoggingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) in C:\TFS\AT_NCSWorkspace\WorkSpaceAPI\src\API\Middlewares\ErrorLoggingMiddleware.cs:line 31
>   ClientConnectionId:3c0ec020-5be1-4bda-adc1-205038682b08```

**Steps to reproduce**

Include a complete code listing (or project/solution) that we can run to reproduce the issue.

Partial code listings, or multiple fragments of code, will slow down our response or cause us to push the issue back to you to provide code to reproduce the issue.

```cs
<code with error and mapping classes>
```

**Environment details**

- linq2db version: 2.6.4 with System.Data.SqlClient 4.6.1
- Database Server: Azure SqlServer
- Database Provider: SqlServer
- Operating system: Windows
- .NET Framework: .net Core 2.2

Comment: I might be wrong, but should not a pool be a singleton? Because being scoped or transient, for each request a new factory will be created, removing the purpose of the pool in the first place

Comment: So this was confusing for me too, but the best explanation I have seen so far is that you do as told. that is, create a connection for every request and dispose of it. In the background .Net framework will maintain the pool. Also as you see here, after injecting the factory as a service dependency, .net core takes care of instantiating and disposing as well.

Comment: My Question really is whether the connection factory instantiation is creating new connections and is it better to implement a static factory

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changed the factory to static. This solved the too many connections problem.

Comment: If this works and solved the problem, you can accept it (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. as the answer?

Comment: This would be the same as creating a singleton, with the advantage that you avoid an static implementation, keeping the code easier to test or mock